# Tensorflow: Using Lambda Layer to index into array

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use a Lambda layer to retrieve values from a fixed array. Here is my toy example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
fixed_array = tf.random.uniform( shape=(5,32) )
index_input = tf.keras.Input( shape=(1,), dtype='int32' )
output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda( lambda x: fixed_array[ x[:,0] ] )( index_input )
model = tf.keras.Model( inputs=index_input, outputs=output )
model.compile()
```

but when run it, I get the following error:

```bash
output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda( lambda x: fixed_array[ x ] )( index_input )
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lambda" (type Lambda).

Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 3 for '{{node lambda/strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](lambda/6, lambda/strided_slice/stack, lambda/strided_slice/stack_1, lambda/strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [5,32], [1,?,1], [1,?,1], [1].

Call arguments received by layer "lambda" (type Lambda):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=int32)
  • mask=None
  • training=None
```

I do not understand the error message: First it notes that the rank is 3 (*Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 3*), but then it writes the rank is 1 (*inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=int32)*).

What is the error message telling me, and how do I fix this exmaple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very cryptic indeed, it does not make too much sense to me either. However, the Numpy style indexing compiles to [`tf.getitem`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#__getitem__), which only support basic indexing not including indexing by tensors, while your `x` variable is a tensor. If you define your lambda function explicitly and print `x`, it will show:

```
Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=int32)
```

It seems however, that you can use [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) to handle tensors of indices, like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

fixed_array = tf.random.uniform( shape=(5,32) )
index_input = tf.keras.Input( shape=(1,), dtype='int32' )
output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda( lambda x: tf.gather(fixed_array, x[:,0]) )( index_input )
model = tf.keras.Model( inputs=index_input, outputs=output )
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())  # you have to specify a loss function
```

and then you can run for example:

```
model.predict(tf.constant([0,2,4]))
```

which will return the specified rows of `fixed_array`.